# Different rendering outputs for -webkit-linear-gradient and linear-gradient with identical parameters

Tags: html, css, colors, linear-gradients

Can someone explain why using `background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, black, red);` produces a different result than `background: linear-gradient(-45deg, black, red);` even though **both have the same values?**

[Difference between -webkit-linear-gradient and linear-gradient with negative deg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5hEO.png)

but `background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, black, red);` (45deg instead of -45deg) produces the same value as `background: linear-gradient(45deg, black, red);` (which is the expected result).

I can't understand why `-webkit-linear-gradient` doesn't give the same result (with identical parameters) as `linear-gradient` when dealing with negative deg.

I hope I explained it clearly :)))

Comment: FYI `-webkit-linear-gradient` is no longer necessary as the `linear-gradient` now has universal support.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of where angles start and the direction is different between `-webkit-linear-gradient` and `linear-gradient`.

In `-webkit-linear-gradient` from: https://webkit.org/blog/1424/css3-gradients/

> angles run counter-clockwise, and 0deg is to the right

In `linear-gradient` from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient

> A value of 0deg is equivalent to to top; increasing values rotate
> clockwise from there.